# Using Sequelize with Node.js and React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I want to use sequelize in my app with mysql.
I think I forget something.. I try to do the configuration, but I have an error : "cannot use new with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature" So how can I use a constructor here .. ? Must I create a component in React ? 
This is my code :

```
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize'

const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://root@localhost:3306/dbtestseq', {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true
} as Sequelize.Options)



export default sequelize
```

Thank you

Comment: I believe the problem is your import statement. It should be something like `const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize')` instead

Comment: I have the same issue and @alisianoi solution solved it for me. I'm not sure why this doesn't work though. Even according to the official Sequelize docs it says to do it this way - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/typescript